# Command window popping up on visual studio when running a program

Tags: visual-studio

I just installed Visual studio to use python.
When I executed `print("hello world")` the command window popped up with the output.

Is there anyway to prevent the command window on windows to pop up when running a program on visual stuio

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The command window represents an executing of your python program, so it will pop up every time you run the python program, and you can do input or output on this window.